# CSS - Unable to get input text and a link on the same line

Tags: css

All-

Googled this and tried for about 20 minutes but just can't seem to figure this out.  Does anyone know why I can't get the Search:  to be on the same line?

I've tried the display: inline, display: block, float:left/right, clear:both, but to no avail.  Even w/chrome inspector I can't figure out why it isn't working properly.

Edit: Pasting relevent code

```
<li>Search: <input type="text" name="quest_search"></li>
```

Corresponding css:

```
header {
    background: #f6f6f6;
    height: 58px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaea;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}
    /* Social Links */
    header aside ul {
        padding-top: 18px;
    }
    /* Main Navigation */
    header .select-menu { display: none; }
    header nav { position: relative; }
    header nav ul {
        list-style: none;
        float: right;
        padding: 22px 0px 0px 0px;
    }
        header nav ul li {
            float: left;
            margin-left: 30px;
            position: relative;
        }       
            header nav ul li a{
                color: #b5b5b5;
                font-size: 12px;
                -webkit-transition:color 0.2s ease-in;  
            -moz-transition:color 0.2s ease-in;  
            -o-transition:color 0.2s ease-in;  
            transition:color 0.2s ease-in;
            }
            header nav ul li a:hover { color: #777; }
            header nav ul li.current a{ color: #555; font-weight: bold; }
            header nav span.arrow {
                width: 24px;
                height: 13px;
                background: url('../images/light-nav_arrow.png') no-repeat;
                display: none;
                position: absolute;
                top: 58px;
            }
```

http://dump.tanaris4.com/so/cfs.html

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please don't ask users to reverse-engineer external sites. Please put the relevant part of your HTML/CSS in your question.

Comment: Done, sorry about that!

Comment: Take your search field out of the `<nav>` element. It's not navigation after all.

Comment: Why exactly did you use `<li>` over `<table>`?

Comment: Don't use the `<center>` element. It's deprecated. In your case, use `text-align: center;`.

Comment: @David Why would he use a table?

Comment: @MiniRagnarok Guess it's more of a personal preference if anything. I'll just back away.

Comment: @David Don't worry. We were all noobs once. Google "tables vs divs". I know that in this case we're talking about lists but it's still relevant. It's a pretty heated subject. As a general rule, don't use tables for anything that isn't tabular data. They're not meant for layout. I'd talk more but I don't want to hijack this question any more than I have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that the `input` in `base.css` has a a `width` of 100%. This means that the width of the `input` will always be 100% of the size of its parent element, which also contains the "search: " text. Change this to something less than 100% and it should work fine.

For example:

```
input[type="password"], input[type="text"], input[type="email"] {
    width: 50%;
}
```

Of course, `width:50%` is just one example of what you can use. `width:auto` and other specific widths will work. Just play around with it and see what works best for you.

Comment: Thanks - can't believe it was so simple. I was like tearing my hair out!

Comment: No problem! Sometimes it is the simplest bugs that are the hardest to find.

Answer (score 2):

Your `base.css` file is giving the `input` a `width: 100%;`. Try giving it a `width: auto`

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
input[name="quest_search"]{
    width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put "Search:" in it's own `<li>` is a simple quick fix.